# Crashlytics (3.10.3, CocoaPods) submit segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

Building on CI (started happening only in the last couple of days, perhaps when the Crashlytics pod was updated... Crashlytics (3.10.3)), I am now getting a segmentation fault when submitting the .ipa file to Crashlytics:

```
2018-06-28 20:11:39.789 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (18)
carchive.sh: line 289: 10426 Segmentation fault
```

Where the carchive.sh step at that point does:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/Crashlytics/submit $GS_FABRIC_API_KEY $GS_FABRIC_BUILD_SECRET -ipaPath "$OUTPUT_IPA_NAME" -groupAliases "$GS_GROUP_TESTER_ID" -notesPath "$release_notes_file"
```

Comment: Reverting to the previous version of the Crashlytics pod (3.10.2) fixes this crash.

Comment: Me too. Using 3.10.3 pod.... Is stackoverflow the issue tracker of Crashlytics beta? (???)

Comment: that is where the Support link goes now, standard for lots of #google products I guess ...

Comment: Btw we're also dealing with it here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12820#issuecomment-401831233 and it seems like a bug in the latest Crashlytics.framework - submit binary segfaults if you specify notes. Remove notes and no crash.

Comment: Thanks Jonny for replying here. Maybe the dashboard could be updated to clarify this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the linked issue, this is still an issue as of Crashlytics 3.10.4. Quickest workaround for now is to downgrade to 3.10.2 (`pod 'Crashlytics', '3.10.2'` in your Podfile and then `pod update Crashlytics`)

For reference, the error I was getting was super vague, even with the `--verbose` flag:

```
ERROR [2018-07-10 23:29:22.01]: fastlane finished with errors/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141:in `user_error!': [!] 2018-07-10 23:29:14.457 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (18) (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneError)
2018-07-10 23:29:14.465 submit Crashlytics: Path to IPA manually provided: ./output/<redacted>/myApp.ipa
2018-07-10 23:29:15.658 submit Crashlytics: Path To App: /var/folders/<redacted>/myApp.app
```

edit: Works again as of 3.10.5 (make sure your crashlytics and fabric frameworks are up to date)

Comment: Yup, 3.10.5 does address the issue :).